# 'Segmentation fault' when trying to set up chatbot ui

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, supabase

I'm currently facing an issue while setting up Chatbot UI v2 on my MacBook Air Sonoma. The primary problem arises when trying to start Supabase services, where I consistently receive a 'Segmentation fault' error. This issue is hindering my progress, and I haven't been able to find a workaround.

Environment Details:

MacBook Air Sonoma
Node.js Version: v16.17.0
Steps Taken to Resolve:

I updated Node.js to version v16.17.0, anticipating this would ensure compatibility with the latest features and stability fixes.
I reinstalled all dependencies within the project, thinking it might resolve any corrupted or outdated modules.
I checked and confirmed that my system resources (memory, CPU) are sufficient, ruling out the possibility of resource constraints causing the error.
Despite these efforts, every time I run the command to start Supabase services, the same 'Segmentation fault' error occurs. This is particularly perplexing as I've followed all the installation and setup guidelines provided for Chatbot UI, available at GitHub - Chatbot UI.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone has encountered a similar issue or can provide insights on what might be causing this and how to resolve it. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend opening an issue on the repo: https://github.com/mckaywrigley/chatbot-ui . The maintainers might be able to help you there.